# Resolving Javascript/jQuery memory leak issues in $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory-leaks

I have an issue with a memory leak I'm trying to trace in a webapp, using jQuery-1.7.1. The app is making a POST request to the server to retrieve some search results using an elaborate form. After I eliminated most of the js code (for leak trace purposes), the bare function looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  // bind the search action
  $('#search-button').unbind('click').click(function() { doSearch(); });
});

function doSearch() {
  // get the query string from the search form
  var query = $('#search-form').serialize();

  // perform search and render results
  $.post('/search', query, function(data){
    // nothing here now (trying to debug)
    data = null;
  }, 'json');

  query = null;
}
```

I can see that the memory consumption accumulates an extra ~1MB every time I hit the search button, even though, in effect, it does nothing. This is a real issue since the app has an "auto-refresh" search mode, where that call is made about once a minute - so if left active it'll jam the browser after a while.

The `data` object returned from the server contains a boolean for success/failure, and an html string to render (pretty big if successful, around 1Mb or so):

```
data = {
  success : true/false,
  html    : "<div id='results'>.....</div>"
}
```

Since I'm down to performing zilch in the actual body of the callback, I suspect that somehow this `data` is not being eliminated from the scope and is aggregated in memory. I've tried setting it to `null` at the end of the callback, but that didn't do the trick. This was tested on both **chrome** and **firefox** (earlier and latest releases for both). Am I missing something? Any thoughts will help - thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? How is this `doSearch` function called?

Comment: How do you retrieve the memory consumption? The memory can also be used for the browsers cache, in that case it wouldn't call it memory-leak. You may send some nocache-headers to avoid this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've used Firefox/Chrome. The `doSearch()` function can be called via a button or through a set-and-forget interval that calls it every 60 seconds or so.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I've used a few traces - `htop` on linux and perfmon + task-manager on windows. On both I see the memory consumption for that process rise significantly on each request. How can I determine if it's actually cache or a leak? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no reliable way to force javascript to do a garbage collection.

You can try adding this line along with the your other line intended to free up memory:

```
query = null;
delete query;
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON format needs to have quotes for each key

Try

```
data = {
  "success" : true/false,
  "html"    : "<div id='results'>.....</div>"
}
```

I am talking about the serverside string output

Comment: The server is python based in this case, and returns a properly formatted json object. I was just cutting corners in the writeup :)